# Q: Error when I open a workflow in Neolane

Tags: neolane

This morning we had a problem with a WKF, when opening it shows the following error:

```
(1677:17349) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:17860) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:18482) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:18490) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:18501) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:19086) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:19095) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:19111) : Expected comment or processing instruction
[...]
(1677:31462) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:31485) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:31938) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:32360) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:32368) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1677:32379) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1686:17) : Expected comment or processing instruction
(1686:26) : Expected comment or processing instruction
Error while parsing XML string '<?xml version='1.0'?>
<workflow background="xtk:backgrounds/neolane.png" errorActivity="query332" errorCount="0" eventCount="111109" keepResult="false" modelName="newWorkflow" 
queryRestart="false" scenario-cs="Notification of the workflow supervisor" scenario-id="2875" schema="axe:usuario" showSQL="false" simulation="false" 
taskCount="96047"><activities><end collision="0" img="xtk:activities/end.png" label="End" mask="0" name="end22473" onError="0" runOnSimulation="true" timezone="_inherit_" x="3928" y="736'

Error while loading memo of table 'workflow' (document of type 'xtk:workflow').
```

So far, it has worked well, but now we can not open it, the error it indicates is the former, but also says that may be due to lack of privileges, this is not possible because I own all privileges on Neolane.

Anyone know how to fix this bug without restoring a backup.
I have consulted with the technical service of Neolane, they have told me that this error is because the version I use Neolane and they say to correct all I can do is upgrade to the new version of Neolane.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is very old, but to me it appears to be related to use of Memo field in the query activity.

If you can share the full context and workflow details, maybe I can help.